# What javascript code/library can I use to open a Pop up on browser window from a small iframe contained in the webpage?

Tags: javascript, fancybox, thickbox

I want to open a remote url inside a javascript popup instead of doing window.open().
I came across libraries like lytebox,lightbox,thickbox which do that if the popup is opened from main webpage.
However my requirement is to open the popup from the link which occurs in a small iframe within the main page.( I can not alter the code of the main page, however Iframe webpage is fully in my control)
When I include those libraries in my iframe webpage, it opens the popup, but restricted only
to within iframe.How to make it appear over whole browser window ?
This is what i want : The user clicks on "click here" and it opens a javascript layer,not
restricted to within iframe.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use

```
parent.document
```

from the iframe to access the parent window, if it is from the same domain. Otherwise, security concerns are raised.

You can inject the javascript by creating a script element in the parent's document, and then will be able to access the necessary functions.